# how to pass array(1) element of array(5,5) to a function in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, multidimensional-array, basic

```vb
Private Sub fun1()
    Dim array(5,5) As Integer
    someinit(array)
    For I As Integer = 0 To 4
        Function (array(I))
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to pass the arrays array(0), array(1), etc to Function(). But getting error:

> Number of indices is less than dimensions of the indexed array

Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of defining arrays in 2 dimensions in VB:

1. Multidimensional arrays: `Dim matrix(5, 5) As Integer`
2. Jagged arrays, i.e., array of arrays: `Dim jagged As Integer()()`

The term "jagged" comes from the fact that every sub-array can have a different lengths. When creating the array, you can only specify the first dimension. The sub-arrays have to be created individually for each position of the main array.

```vb
Dim jagged As Integer()() = New Integer(5)() {}
jagged(0) = New Integer(5) {}
jagged(1) = New Integer(5) {}
...
```

Only in the second case you can select a one-dimensional array by specifying one index. For multidimensional arrays you must always specify two indexes and the result is always one "cell" (an `Integer` in this case).

Now `jagged(i)` is a one dimensional array you can pass to your function.

---

Another way to solve the problem is use a 2-d multidimensional array and pass the whole array plus a row number to your function. Then let your function loop through the columns of this row.

---

Note also that in VB you specify the highest index when you create an array, not the size of the array. I.e., `Dim array(5,5) as Integer` is a 6 x 6 matrix, not a 5 x 5 matrix!

See also:

- [Arrays in Visual Basic (Microsoft Learn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)
- [Visual Basic Jagged Arrays (tutlane)](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/visual-basic/vb-jagged-arrays)